# App crashes in release mode, but doesn't crash when zombies enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my app.  It crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS in release mode, but when I try checking for zombies, it doesn't crash via instruments.  Without fail, I turn off zombie detection and it crashes.

When it does crash the only thing I can tell is that the very latest call in the vm allocation shows this viewDidLoad.  So I'm wondering if there's something wrong here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //load abstract
    if ( self.abstractId > 0 ){
        [self startQuery:@selector(getAbstractWithId:)];
    }

    //setup nav bar
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:[self makeFavoriteButton]];


    //add link attributes
    self.linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithHexString:emaGreen],
                            NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlinePatternSolid)};


    //create text view
    UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    tv.editable = NO;
    tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    tv.text = @" ";
    tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tv.scrollEnabled = YES;
    tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    tv.linkTextAttributes = self.linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
    tv.delegate = self;

    // set the scroll indicators between nav and tabs
    tv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,
                                                0,
                                                CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame),
                                                0);

    //add to property and view
    self.tv = tv;
    [self.view addSubview:tv];

    //Create spinner view
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    self.hud = hud;

}
```

What other debugging options do I have here?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try breakpoints to see which line is crashing.

Comment: Did you check the scheme to make sure that the Instruments build and the release build are being built the same way?

Comment: When you enable zombies, the whole point is that the app won't crash any more. Instead, you should see some output in the debug console when you try to do some bad memory access. Look for these messages when debugging with zombies enabled.

Comment: Is getAbstractWithId a valid selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.  Strangely, I finally got a console output in zombies, with the following KVO error `message received but not handled.` 
Which I was able to track down to an observer that was not removed when dealloc'd.  Worst bug ever. ugh.  Thanks for the help!

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.queryQueue removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess it's this line:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];`

To quote the documentation for the parameters of `UIControl`:

> target: The target object—that is, the object to which the action message is sent. If this is nil, the responder chain is searched for an object willing to respond to the action message
>
> action: A selector identifying an action message. It cannot be NULL

Strangely, this is not specified for `UIBarButtonItem`'s initializer, but I see no reason why it shouldn't be true there as well, unless that class actually checks these parameters for `null` and behaves accordingly.

Perhaps your bar button item is trying to access the `null` selector to send it and is crashing there, or is trying to send it to some object that has already been released. This might only be brought on by some optimization -- for example, perhaps in release mode the button grabs a pointer to the function that would be called by a message send, instead of sending the message, as an optimization.

At the very least, passing `nil` there seems like mistake.

Comment: thanks but this didn't solve the problem.  Although i did implement a stub action to handle the nil.